# Using xUnit inlineData when a parameter is a long string

Tags: c#, json, testing, serialization, xunit

I am trying to convert 4 almost identical testcases into one, where the one instead uses xUnits InlineData.

The thing is that the parameter, which I want to differ is a long string - actually a JSON-"string" with small changes. It goes like this (I've only taken the relevant):

```
....
....
        var mockHttp = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        mockHttp
            .Protected()
            .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
                "SendAsync",
                ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
                ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
            .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent( // the below part is the only thing that differs
                    "{'content':[" +
                        "{'Id':'00001', 'eNumber':'001', 'isOwner': true, 'isAlone':false}," +
                        "{'Id':'00001', 'eNumber':'no', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':false}," +
                        "{'Id':'00001', 'eNumber':'no', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':false}," +
                        "{'Id':'00001', 'eNumber':'no', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':false}," +
                        "]}"
                    )
            })
            .Verifiable();

        var httpClient = new HttpClient(mockHttp.Object)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://something.com/")
        };
```

The next test contains the same, but with another 'content', that goes like this:

```
....
....
                   "{'content':[" +
                    "{'Id':'00001', 'eNumber':'no', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':false}," +
                    "{'Id':'00001', 'eNumber':'002', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':true}," +
                    "{'Id':'00001', 'eNumber':'no', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':false}," +
                    "{'Id':'00001', 'eNumber':'no', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':false}," +
                    "]}"
....
....
```

and a third goes like this:

```
....
....
                   "{'content':[" +
                    "{'Id':'00001', 'eNumber':'no', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':false}," +
                    "{'Id':'00001', 'eNumber':'no', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':true}," +
                    "{'Id':'00001', 'eNumber':'007', 'isOwner': true, 'isAlone':true}," +
                    "{'Id':'00001', 'eNumber':'003', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':false}," +
                    "]}"
....
....
```

and so forth with the two next. 
So I am wondering if there is a smart way to put the 5 types of contents inside a InlineData as a parameter - and thereby somehow save a lot of copied code? There probably is, but I still havent figured out how, without actually writing a lot of code anyway.

Writing the tests as 5 individual tests all goes green, so the only thing I am looking for is a smarter way to write the code, making it cleaner and easier to read, by only changing the parameter/string inside StringContent.

**Update as per question in comments:**

The class I am testing goes something like this:

```
....
....

        var httpResponseMessage = await User(// something);


        if (!httpResponseMessage .IsSuccessStatusCode) return;

        var content = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var deserializedContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(content); // it fails here...

....
....
```

my UserModel class looks like this:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public UserModelDto[] {get; set;}
}
```

and my UserModelDto class looks like this:

```
    public class UserModelDto
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string ENumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsOwner { get; set; }
    public bool IsAlone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You could create a model to hold the data and use the [`MemberDataAttribute`](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/) to use an `IEnumerable<object[]>` as your test source, where the elements of that test source are arrays of your object model. In the test you can then serialize these objects to strings.

Answer (score 2):

Extending on my comment and providing an answer, you can use `MemberDataAttribute` or `ClassDataAttribute` to achieve this. This example uses `MemberDataAttribute`.

First create a class to represent your model.

```cs
public class UserModel
{
    [JsonProperty("content")]
    public UserModelDto[] {get; set;}
}

public class UserModelDto
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("eNumber")]
    public string ENumber { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("isOwner")]
    public bool IsOwner { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("isAlone")]
    public bool IsAlone { get; set; }
}
```

Add a `public static IEnumerable<object[]>` property, or method, to your test class, which also contains your test scenarios.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestCaseScenarios
    => new object[][]
       {
           new object[]
           {
               new UserModel
               {
                   Contents = new[]
                   {
                       new UserModelDto
                       {
                           Id = "00001",
                           ENumber = "no",
                           IsOwner = false,
                           IsAlone = false
                       },
                       new UserModelDto
                       {
                           Id = "00001",
                           ENumber = "007",
                           IsOwner = true,
                           IsAlone = true
                       },
                   }
               }
           },
           new object[] { } //etc
       }
```

Apply the `MemberDataAttribute` to your test

```cs
[Theory] // Tests which accept parameters require the TheoryAttribute, instead of FactAttribute
[MemberData(nameof(TestCaseScenarios))]
public async Task PerformingAction_WithCriteria_ReturnsExpectedThing(UserModel userModel)
{
    // Serialize userModelto create a string
    var userModelAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userModel);
    // Create the StringContent object
    var stringContent = new StringContent(userModelAsString);
    // Create a HttpClient whose BaseAddress is the host address

    var mockHttp = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    mockHttp
        .Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
            "SendAsync",
            ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent(stringContent)
        })
        .Verifiable();

    var httpClient = new HttpClient(mockHttp.Object) { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://something.com") };
}
```

Comment: yeah okay - I was hoping to be able to place the JSON (or string) as a string and not splitting them up in Id, eNumber, IsOwner, IsAlone for each test, but when doing that it fails in the conversion using "... new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testData))"

Comment: What do you mean by "when doing that it fails in the conversion"? What is the error message?

Comment: "Error converting value "{'content':[{'id':'00001', 'eNumber':'no', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':true},{'id':'00001', 'eNumber':'001', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':false},{'id':'00001', 'eNumber':'no', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':false},{'id':'00001', 'eNumber':'no', 'isOwner': false, 'isAlone':false},]}" to type 'userModelDto'". I've updated my question with more info about the classes - hope i makes sense.

Comment: @badaboomskey The updated code isn't valid, you're missing a property name in `UserModel`, I've updated my answer to change the design of the model classes to match yours.

Comment: Arrghh - I found out what I was doing wrong. The deserialization and serialization part was causing the fail. With great inspiration from your answer, but instead using a single string that contains the whole 'content' I saved many lines of code. Awesome and thanks for the quick answer. I will update my question with the solution after I've got some sleep - been stuck with this problem for hours.

Answer (score 0):

FYI for those who come across this question in google when searching for Xunit inlinedata for a long variable.

this was giving errors. [InlineData(0)]

this is the solution  [InlineData((long)0)]   where 0 is my input variable.